# Getting error: "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(Code=EXC_I386_GPFLT) during SOAP request

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my objective C code I'm trying to access SOAP web service but getting error as error: **"Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(Code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)"** near following line.

```
NSString *httpBodySoapMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                     @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"......
                                     "</x:Envelope>\n", _encryptedUsername,_encryptedPassword, nonce, digest];
```

**Below is my complete code.**

```
#pragma mark - login request method

- (void)sendValidateEmailRequest {
    NSString *nonce = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)(NSTimeInterval)([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970])];
    NSString *digest = [Utils sha1:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", _textUsername.text, nonce, _textPassword]];    // input is forsha
    NSString *httpBodySoapMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                 @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                                 "<x:Envelope xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:mob=\"https://billing.eukhost.com/webservices/mobile_service_new?wsdl\">\n"
                                 "<x:Header/>\n"
                                 "<x:Body>\n"
                                 "<mob:validate_email>\n"
                                 "<mob:email>%@</mob:email>\n"
                                 "<mob:password>%@</mob:password>\n"
                                 "<mob:nonce>%@</mob:nonce>\n"
                                 "<mob:digest>%@</mob:digest>\n"
                                 "</mob:validate_email>\n"
                                 "</x:Body>\n"
                                 "</x:Envelope>\n", _encryptedUsername, _encryptedPassword, nonce, digest];

    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:DEMO_URL]];
    [urlRequest setValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [urlRequest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", DEMO_URL, VALIDATE_EMAIL] forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [urlRequest setValue:@"Basic YjBlMDc2ZjAxZjFjZjAyODc6ODQ0NzI0ZGMyYjMwNWM4MzA=" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [urlRequest setValue:_encryptedUsername forHTTPHeaderField:@"PHP_AUTH_USER"];
    [urlRequest setValue:_encryptedPassword forHTTPHeaderField:@"PHP_AUTH_PW"];

    NSString* deviceId = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString]; // IOS 6+
    [urlRequest setValue:deviceId forHTTPHeaderField:@"PHP_AUTH_DEVICE"];
    // @"96c6754c9dc3b654517c5"

    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)(httpBodySoapMsg.length)];
    [urlRequest setValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:[httpBodySoapMsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    RestApi *restApi = [RestApi sharedManager];
    restApi.delegate = self;
    [restApi httpRequest:urlRequest withResponseId:VALIDATE_EMAIL_ID];
}
```

Comment: At which line exactly you have this error ? "near httpBodySoapMsg parameter" as not clear at all

Comment: @Anton Malmygin - please check updates

Comment: Did you tried to set a break point on this line and check values of _encryptedUsername, _encryptedPassword, nonce, digest ?

Comment: Are `_encryptedUsername`, `_encryptedPassword`, `nonce`, `digest` really NSObject? Since a bad placeHolder should cause a EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: @Larme - _encryptedUsername, _encryptedPassword, nonce, digest are NSString type

Comment: @Anton Malmygin - I have created property of NSString for both encryptedUsername and encryptedPassword. \@property (assign, nonatomic) NSString *encryptedUsername;
\@property (assign, nonatomic) NSString *encryptedPassword; But at breakpoints, I don't getting any values inside these properties

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declare your properties as `strong` not `assign`

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *encryptedUsername;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *encryptedPassword;
```

Comment: Yes you are right. Solved the problem. Thanks. But I have one question. We always use strong with UI components. So why we are using Strong with NSString? Whats wrong with assign? Can I use retain?

Comment: just now I executed code successfully with retain. It is also working.

Comment: 'strong' is (approximativly) like an alias for 'retain' when you using ARC.